# Detect facebook video URLs with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I detect a Facebook video URL by Javascript?

Comment: Could you give me one Facebook video URL? I don't know how they look, I don't use Facebook :P

Comment: Have you tried my answer ? Was it working ? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a pretty bad way to get it done, but facebook videos should match something like this :

```
var url   = "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=7489378947389&set=t.674367&type=3&theater";
var regex = /^http(?:s?):\/\/www\.facebook\.com\/photo.php\?v=(\d+)/;

if (url.match(regex))
    alert('This is a neat facebook video !')
```

If I say this is a bad way to achieve this, it's because facebook keep changing their url, I've never seen something constant on their side. Youtube URL are a way more reliable, for example.

This regex should work as facebook format their video URL today, and maybe will not in a few month.

Answer (score 0):

`Regex Reg=new Regex(@"^http(?:s?):\/\/www\.facebook\.com\/video.php\?v=(\d+)");`

Just Remoeved the `/` before `^http` and at last of URL.

I it modified like this for using in C#... it worked for me!

Comment: Javascript ? C# ? I'm confused